# How to rewrite code using Promise.then instead of using await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

It's my understanding that async/await is syntactic sugar for Promises.  I thought *perhaps* this might mean that we can rewrite async/await style code using Promise.then.

Using async/await we can await a `Promise` in a for loop.  Can we do something like this with Promise.then?  How would we rewrite this using `Promise.then` instead of `await`?

```
let zeros = new Array(10000).fill(0);

(async () => {
    for (let zero of zeros) {
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)); //1
        console.log(zero);
    }
})();
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that particular code could be written entirely without promises, using the callback of `setTimeout` directly instead of using it to resolve a promise to then do an action. Not an answer to your question (Ahrengot's is sufficient, I believe) but worth mentioning regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Without `await` there are still several ways to get it done. I believe the closest to the original is to chain promises:

```js
let zeros = new Array(10000).fill(0);

let p = Promise.resolve(); // the promise that will be chained
for (let zero of zeros) {
    p = p.then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(zero));
}
```

You can imagine this as:

```
let p = Promise.resolve()
         .then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(0))
         .then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(0))
         .then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(0))
         .then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(0))
         // ... etc ...
         .then(() => new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 1000)))
         .then(() => console.log(0));
```

### After the loop

In the original code the code *after* the `for` loop will only execute when all timers have expired, i.e. when the last promise has resolved.

So also that remaining part of the code is executed *asynchronously*. Without `await` you need to introduce this asynchronous behaviour -- again -- with a `then` callback:

```
p.then(() => {
    /* remaining code */
});
```

Comment: This is a very thoughtful answer - thanks.  It is my understanding that the for loop may exit before all of the Promises resolve.  Is it correct that this doesn't function the same way as the given example?

Comment: It does not function in the same way: the original `for` loop will not end synchronously, ... due to the `await` mechanics. In the `await`-less version this corresponds to putting the remaining code also in a `then` callback. See addition to answer.